# Perl : Error Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

Hello I am executing the below script but facing following error :

```
Global symbol "$line2" requires explicit package name at Job_Monitoring.pl line 40.
Global symbol "$line2" requires explicit package name at Job_Monitoring.pl line 42.
Global symbol "$line3" requires explicit package name at Job_Monitoring.pl line 43.
Global symbol "$line3" requires explicit package name at Job_Monitoring.pl line 45.
Execution of Job_Monitoring.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Below is the code.I am getting errors where I am trying to compare 10th field of two files and if it matches then print the entire line :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", "backup_report.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile, ">", "long_running_jobs.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile1, ">", "active_jobs.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile2, ">", "hung_jobs.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile3, "<", "hung_jobs_old.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile4, ">", "active_jobs_all_fields.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile5, ">", "hung_jobs_old.txt" or die $!;
print $outputfile1 "################Active Jobs################\n\n";
print $outputfile "################Long Running Jobs################\n\n";
print $outputfile2 "################Hung Jobs################\n\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
no warnings 'numeric';
chomp $line;
my @data = split (' ', $line);
if ($data[1] == 0 and $data[2] == 1)
{
    if (! -f $outputfile3)
    {
    print $outputfile3 "$line";
    }
    print $outputfile4 "$line";
    my $acttime=scalar(localtime($data[6]));
    print $outputfile1 "$data[0] $data[3] $data[5] $acttime \n";
    my $currt = time;
    my $efft=($currt-$data[6])/3600;
    if ($efft > 48)
      {
    my $longtime=scalar(localtime($data[6]));
    print $outputfile "$data[0] $data[3] $data[5] $longtime \n";
      }
}
}
my @arr=<$outputfile1>;
my @arr1=<$outputfile3>;
foreach $line2(@arr)
{
my @split=split(' ',$line2);
foreach $line3(@arr1)
{
my @split1=split(' ',$line3);
if($split[9] eq $split1[9])
    {
    print $outputfile2 "$split[0] $split[3] $split[5] $split[6] \n";
    }
print $outputfile5 $outputfile2;
}
}
close $fh;
close $outputfile;
close $outputfile1;
close $outputfile2;
close $outputfile3;
close $outputfile4;
close $outputfile5;
```

Comment: What is it that you think `if (! -f $outputfile3)` is doing?

Comment: [Learning Perl](http://www.learning-perl.com)

Answer (score 2):

Under [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict), you have to declare each variable used, even the loop variables:

```
foreach my $line2 (@arr)
```

Comment: Thanks. Also I am getting following error :                                                                             No such file or directory at Job_Monitoring.pl line 9. I wanted to create file : $outputfile3 if it doesn't exists from $fh based on the conditions mentioned in the script however this didn't worked. Please help I am very new to PERL.

Comment: You can't read from a file that doesn't exist. If you want to create a new file, you need to open it for writing.

Comment: @RahulM Files only get created in clobber and append mode. perldoc is your friend here: [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.